# frontmatter page numbers in the Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I have a problem with the frontmatter page numbers in the Table of Contents (TOC). For the mainmatter, everything works just fine.

My abstracts start at page V and appear at page V in the TOC.
The acknowledgment is at page xi and appears at xi in the TOC.
The "List of figures" and "List of tables" start at pages xvii and xix. However, they are at xvi and xviii in the TOC (1 page shift).

How could I fix that?

tnx,

Farzin

```
\frontmatter
\input{head/titlepage.tex}
\include{head/dedication}
\include{head/abstracts}
\include{head/acknowledgements}

\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of figures} 
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of tables} 
\listoftables

\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\mainmatter
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all always post full minimal examples, we cannot see your document class etc. Your `\addcontentsline` is probably not executed on the proper page as perhaps `\listoffigures` may start with, say `\chapter*` (including a `\clearpage or \cleardoublepage`)

I'd recommend you have a look at the `tocbibind` package which will defedine `\listoffigures` and friends such that it include a `\addcontentsline` and executes it a the proper place.

BTW: the `memoir` class has this sort of thing build in so a better base class may also be a good idea.